# Why is language change not taking effect?

Tags: language-support, ibus, pinyin, korean

**Question:** Why is the/How to fix language input not changing even after I switch to next text entry source?

**What I did:** I wanted to install text-entry support for **Hangul** `ibus-hangul` (Korean, package also includes Hanja, the Chinese character equivalent for some Korean words) *This worked for me before.*; **Simplified Chinese/Pinyin** `ibus-sunpinyin`, and **Traditional Chinese/Pinyin** `ibus-chewing`.

- Terminal: `sudo apt-get install ibus-hangul`, `sudo apt-get install ibus-sunpinyin`, `sudo apt-get install ibus-chewing`
- Terminal: `sudo reboot`, computer reboots
- Language Support: Add `Chinese (simplified)`, `Chinese (traditional)`, `Korean`.
- Text Entry: Add `Korean (Hangul) (IBus)`, `Chinese (SunPinyin) (IBus)`, `Chinese (Chewing) (IBus)`
- Terminal: `sudo reboot`, computer reboots

**Anomalies observed:**

Please refer to the following figures in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyEX9.png) for reference.

- Under Hangul entry mode, I don't see the settings for the language for Hangul/Hanja.
  ***Figure 1 (Expected)*** vs.
  ***Figure 2 (What is appearing right now)***
- After changing languages, the other language icon appears in the taskbar but I cannot type in desired language.
- Under Hangul entry mode, if I click Keyboard Layout Chart, the layout chart is for Korean (101/104 key compatible), which was *another* text-entry mode in Text Entry.
- Under SunPinyin and Chewing entry modes, if I click Keyboard Layout Chart, the layout chart is for English (US).
- In Language Support even after installing the languages they appear grayed out. The only language that is in solid black is English and English (US).
  ***Figure 3***

Thank you! All help is appreciated :)

Comment: Figure 2 looks buggy (I can't reproduce it). Can you open _Text Entry_, select _Korean (Hangul) (Ibus)_, and click the tool icon. That should open _IBusHangul Setup_. Please enable "Start in hangul mode" and check if that makes a difference.

Comment: Hi @GunnarHjalmarsson thanks for your comment. Start in Hangul mode has already been checked off; the problem is still there.

Comment: You may want to try [Fcitx](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html#complex) instead. (Figure 3 has nothing to do with this problem. You can click the Help button in _Language Support_ to read about how it works.)

Comment: Hi @GunnarHjalmarsson I was considering using Fcitx but I kind of like the iBus layout better, but if this problem is unsolvable then I will go ahead and transition to Fcitx. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is probably not unresolvable, but I'm out of ideas. And it works fine for me on Ubuntu 16.10. Which version are you on btw?